# Mockito or Mockito-inline to skip static initialisation block

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am working on Junits using Mockito framework to write junits to my module. I have a situation where I need to skip a static initialization block while mocking a class. Here is the situation:

```
class A extends B{
    
}

class B{
    
    C c = new C();
}

class C{
    
    static{
        //some code
    }
}
```

I want to write a JUnit for class A. When I trying to make a mock of it, it fails and the error message is related to static block.

The test class is like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class})
public class ATest{
}
```

I am able to achieve this by PowerMock but I do not want to use it and wanted tet this using Mockito only.

I read about Mockito-Inline but not able to find any success yet.

Any idea how I can skip the static block initialization.

Thanks,
Atul

Comment: Is this static block really needed? In some of the cases, this would be refactorable.

Comment: Yes, but I am writing the test cases for existing code and I have no authority to change the code.